# Render a report page by page in Stimulsoft Report Web MVC 2015.2?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, stimulsoft

We are using Stimulsoft Report Web MVC 2015.2
I want to report from huge data, so I need to render the report page by page as follows:

> After click on Report Button, Stimulsoft Report Viewer should be shown
>   with rendered page 1, after that another pages should be rendering in
>   background and Report Viewer total pages number should be update to
>   total rendered pages, and user can navigate between rendered pages

Is it possible in Stimulsoft Report Web MVC 2015.2? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

No, it's impossible. There are some features that don't all to render the report page by page. For example, if you set the **Print On** property to **Except Last Page** or use the **PageNofM** system variable.

The whole report should be rendered before it will be shown in Viewer.

Comment: So, How to we handle long time process reports?

Comment: You could use the **Stop Before Page** property of the report.
This will stop rendering of the report.

Comment: @HighAley - Is this impossible also for the Silverlight version?  I would presume so.